r future_map with ggpredict
I have generated 10 model summaries after fitting the same model on 10 different subsets of the dataset which is as follows
library(mice)
data("nhanes")
head(nhanes)

imp <- mice(nhanes, print = FALSE, m = 10, seed = 24415)
df <- complete(imp, "long")
model_fit <- lapply(1:10, function(i) {
  model = lm(bmi ~ lspline(age, c(5, 10)) + hyp + chl,
             data = subset(df, `.imp`==i))
})

From this I get different ggpredict objects
ggpredict(model_fit[[1]], c("age[all]", "hyp"))
ggpredict(model_fit[[2]], c("age[all]", "hyp"))
ggpredict(model_fit[[3]], c("age[all]", "hyp"))
ggpredict(model_fit[[4]], c("age[all]", "hyp"))
ggpredict(model_fit[[5]], c("age[all]", "hyp"))
ggpredict(model_fit[[6]], c("age[all]", "hyp"))
ggpredict(model_fit[[7]], c("age[all]", "hyp"))
ggpredict(model_fit[[8]], c("age[all]", "hyp"))
ggpredict(model_fit[[9]], c("age[all]", "hyp"))
ggpredict(model_fit[[10]], c("age[all]", "hyp"))

I am looking for an efficient way to a) Estimate the average of all the ggpredict objects by hp and age
I am trying to use future_map function with ggpredict. This is my code
library(lspline)
library(purrr)
library(furrr)

plan(multisession, workers =20)
test1 <- future_map(model_fit, ggpredict,  c("age[all]", "hyp"), library(lspline), progress = TRUE)

I get a warning and an error message
Warning: could not access model information. Warning could not find any variables for the specified model component.
i In index = 1.
i With name: modelStruct
Caused by error in !is.null(model_Info) && model_info$is_trial:
! invalid y type in x && y
However if I switch to regular map function, there is no error or warning everything works fine, it just takes too long.
test1 <- map(model_list[[1]] , ggpredict,  c("age[all]", "hyp"))

I like to know where I am going wrong or the right way to specify future_map to work with ggpredict. Thanks in advance.

library(lspline) inside future_map() may be causing the problem.
The following works:
(Sometimes it is necessary to explicitly load a package for each worker using packages = c("package_name") as an extra argument.)
[Updated for the second model with lspline.]
library(mice)
library(ggeffects)
library(tidyverse)
library(furrr)

imp <- mice(nhanes, print = FALSE, m = 10, seed = 24415)
df <- complete(imp, "long")
model_fit <- lapply(1:10, function(i) {
  model = lm(bmi ~ age + hyp + chl,
             data = subset(df, `.imp`==i))
})

plan(multisession, workers = 10)

future_map(model_fit, ggpredict, c("age[all]", "hyp"), progress = TRUE) 
#> [[1]]
#> # Predicted values of bmi
#> 
#> hyp: 1
#> 
#> age | Predicted |       95% CI
#> ------------------------------
#>   1 |     28.38 | 26.67, 30.08
#>   2 |     24.21 | 22.71, 25.71
#>   3 |     20.05 | 17.13, 22.96
#> 
#> hyp: 2
#> 
#> age | Predicted |       95% CI
#> ------------------------------
#>   1 |     31.82 | 28.07, 35.58
#>   2 |     27.66 | 24.88, 30.43
#>   3 |     23.49 | 20.63, 26.35
#> 
#> Adjusted for:
#> * chl = 195.08
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # Predicted values of bmi
#> 
#> hyp: 1
#> 
#> age | Predicted |       95% CI
#> ------------------------------
#>   1 |     29.35 | 26.83, 31.87
#>   2 |     26.01 | 23.56, 28.46
#>   3 |     22.67 | 17.89, 27.44
#> 
#> hyp: 2
#> 
#> age | Predicted |       95% CI
#> ------------------------------
#>   1 |     29.35 | 23.58, 35.13
#>   2 |     26.01 | 22.02, 30.00
#>   3 |     22.67 | 18.73, 26.61
#> 
#> Adjusted for:
#> * chl = 192.88
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # Predicted values of bmi
#> 
#> hyp: 1
#> 
#> age | Predicted |       95% CI
#> ------------------------------
#>   1 |     27.30 | 25.25, 29.35
#>   2 |     25.40 | 23.54, 27.26
#>   3 |     23.51 | 20.08, 26.94
#> 
#> hyp: 2
#> 
#> age | Predicted |       95% CI
#> ------------------------------
#>   1 |     28.87 | 24.24, 33.49
#>   2 |     26.97 | 23.43, 30.52
#>   3 |     25.08 | 21.50, 28.66
#> 
#> Adjusted for:
#> * chl = 194.64
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> # Predicted values of bmi
#> 
#> hyp: 1
#> 
#> age | Predicted |       95% CI
#> ------------------------------
#>   1 |     27.79 | 25.56, 30.03
#>   2 |     24.66 | 22.52, 26.80
#>   3 |     21.52 | 17.66, 25.38
#> 
#> hyp: 2
#> 
#> age | Predicted |       95% CI
#> ------------------------------
#>   1 |     31.87 | 27.10, 36.63
#>   2 |     28.73 | 25.20, 32.26
#>   3 |     25.59 | 22.01, 29.17
#> 
#> Adjusted for:
#> * chl = 199.32
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> # Predicted values of bmi
#> 
#> hyp: 1
#> 
#> age | Predicted |       95% CI
#> ------------------------------
#>   1 |     28.85 | 26.72, 30.99
#>   2 |     24.47 | 22.75, 26.20
#>   3 |     20.09 | 16.79, 23.40
#> 
#> hyp: 2
#> 
#> age | Predicted |       95% CI
#> ------------------------------
#>   1 |     31.72 | 27.13, 36.32
#>   2 |     27.34 | 23.62, 31.07
#>   3 |     22.96 | 18.94, 26.99
#> 
#> Adjusted for:
#> * chl = 192.36
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> # Predicted values of bmi
#> 
#> hyp: 1
#> 
#> age | Predicted |       95% CI
#> ------------------------------
#>   1 |     29.45 | 27.44, 31.45
#>   2 |     25.67 | 23.80, 27.54
#>   3 |     21.89 | 18.49, 25.30
#> 
#> hyp: 2
#> 
#> age | Predicted |       95% CI
#> ------------------------------
#>   1 |     30.64 | 26.49, 34.80
#>   2 |     26.87 | 23.77, 29.96
#>   3 |     23.09 | 19.84, 26.34
#> 
#> Adjusted for:
#> * chl = 192.56
#> 
#> [[7]]
#> # Predicted values of bmi
#> 
#> hyp: 1
#> 
#> age | Predicted |       95% CI
#> ------------------------------
#>   1 |     29.55 | 27.64, 31.46
#>   2 |     25.64 | 23.98, 27.30
#>   3 |     21.73 | 18.87, 24.58
#> 
#> hyp: 2
#> 
#> age | Predicted |       95% CI
#> ------------------------------
#>   1 |     30.48 | 27.60, 33.37
#>   2 |     26.57 | 24.31, 28.84
#>   3 |     22.66 | 19.79, 25.53
#> 
#> Adjusted for:
#> * chl = 192.92
#> 
#> [[8]]
#> # Predicted values of bmi
#> 
#> hyp: 1
#> 
#> age | Predicted |       95% CI
#> ------------------------------
#>   1 |     28.04 | 26.02, 30.07
#>   2 |     25.29 | 23.62, 26.97
#>   3 |     22.55 | 19.48, 25.62
#> 
#> hyp: 2
#> 
#> age | Predicted |       95% CI
#> ------------------------------
#>   1 |     29.09 | 25.15, 33.04
#>   2 |     26.34 | 23.11, 29.58
#>   3 |     23.60 | 19.96, 27.23
#> 
#> Adjusted for:
#> * chl = 187.20
#> 
#> [[9]]
#> # Predicted values of bmi
#> 
#> hyp: 1
#> 
#> age | Predicted |       95% CI
#> ------------------------------
#>   1 |     28.35 | 26.33, 30.37
#>   2 |     25.06 | 22.85, 27.26
#>   3 |     21.76 | 17.69, 25.84
#> 
#> hyp: 2
#> 
#> age | Predicted |       95% CI
#> ------------------------------
#>   1 |     30.93 | 26.65, 35.21
#>   2 |     27.63 | 24.85, 30.41
#>   3 |     24.34 | 21.49, 27.19
#> 
#> Adjusted for:
#> * chl = 194.56
#> 
#> [[10]]
#> # Predicted values of bmi
#> 
#> hyp: 1
#> 
#> age | Predicted |       95% CI
#> ------------------------------
#>   1 |     28.54 | 26.74, 30.34
#>   2 |     25.15 | 23.50, 26.79
#>   3 |     21.75 | 18.64, 24.87
#> 
#> hyp: 2
#> 
#> age | Predicted |       95% CI
#> ------------------------------
#>   1 |     32.04 | 27.92, 36.15
#>   2 |     28.65 | 25.61, 31.68
#>   3 |     25.25 | 22.25, 28.26
#> 
#> Adjusted for:
#> * chl = 199.08

Created on 2024-04-25 with reprex v2.1.0
library(lspline)
library(furrr)
library(mice)
library(ggeffects)

imp <- mice(nhanes, print = FALSE, m = 10, seed = 24415)
df <- complete(imp, "long")
model_fit <- lapply(1:10, function(i) {
  model = lm(bmi ~ lspline(age, c(5, 10)) + hyp + chl,
             data = subset(df, `.imp`==i))
})

plan(multisession, workers = 10)
future_map(model_fit, ggpredict,  c("age[all]", "hyp"), progress = TRUE)
#> [[1]]
#> # Predicted values of bmi
#> 
#> hyp: 1
#> 
#> age | Predicted |       95% CI
#> ------------------------------
#>   1 |     28.38 | 26.67, 30.08
#>   2 |     24.21 | 22.71, 25.71
#>   3 |     20.05 | 17.13, 22.96
#> 
#> hyp: 2
#> 
#> age | Predicted |       95% CI
#> ------------------------------
#>   1 |     31.82 | 28.07, 35.58
#>   2 |     27.66 | 24.88, 30.43
#>   3 |     23.49 | 20.63, 26.35
#> 
#> Adjusted for:
#> * chl = 195.08
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # Predicted values of bmi
#> 
#> hyp: 1
#> 
#> age | Predicted |       95% CI
#> ------------------------------
#>   1 |     29.35 | 26.83, 31.87
#>   2 |     26.01 | 23.56, 28.46
#>   3 |     22.67 | 17.89, 27.44
#> 
#> hyp: 2
#> 
#> age | Predicted |       95% CI
#> ------------------------------
#>   1 |     29.35 | 23.58, 35.13
#>   2 |     26.01 | 22.02, 30.00
#>   3 |     22.67 | 18.73, 26.61
#> 
#> Adjusted for:
#> * chl = 192.88
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # Predicted values of bmi
#> 
#> hyp: 1
#> 
#> age | Predicted |       95% CI
#> ------------------------------
#>   1 |     27.30 | 25.25, 29.35
#>   2 |     25.40 | 23.54, 27.26
#>   3 |     23.51 | 20.08, 26.94
#> 
#> hyp: 2
#> 
#> age | Predicted |       95% CI
#> ------------------------------
#>   1 |     28.87 | 24.24, 33.49
#>   2 |     26.97 | 23.43, 30.52
#>   3 |     25.08 | 21.50, 28.66
#> 
#> Adjusted for:
#> * chl = 194.64
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> # Predicted values of bmi
#> 
#> hyp: 1
#> 
#> age | Predicted |       95% CI
#> ------------------------------
#>   1 |     27.79 | 25.56, 30.03
#>   2 |     24.66 | 22.52, 26.80
#>   3 |     21.52 | 17.66, 25.38
#> 
#> hyp: 2
#> 
#> age | Predicted |       95% CI
#> ------------------------------
#>   1 |     31.87 | 27.10, 36.63
#>   2 |     28.73 | 25.20, 32.26
#>   3 |     25.59 | 22.01, 29.17
#> 
#> Adjusted for:
#> * chl = 199.32
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> # Predicted values of bmi
#> 
#> hyp: 1
#> 
#> age | Predicted |       95% CI
#> ------------------------------
#>   1 |     28.85 | 26.72, 30.99
#>   2 |     24.47 | 22.75, 26.20
#>   3 |     20.09 | 16.79, 23.40
#> 
#> hyp: 2
#> 
#> age | Predicted |       95% CI
#> ------------------------------
#>   1 |     31.72 | 27.13, 36.32
#>   2 |     27.34 | 23.62, 31.07
#>   3 |     22.96 | 18.94, 26.99
#> 
#> Adjusted for:
#> * chl = 192.36
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> # Predicted values of bmi
#> 
#> hyp: 1
#> 
#> age | Predicted |       95% CI
#> ------------------------------
#>   1 |     29.45 | 27.44, 31.45
#>   2 |     25.67 | 23.80, 27.54
#>   3 |     21.89 | 18.49, 25.30
#> 
#> hyp: 2
#> 
#> age | Predicted |       95% CI
#> ------------------------------
#>   1 |     30.64 | 26.49, 34.80
#>   2 |     26.87 | 23.77, 29.96
#>   3 |     23.09 | 19.84, 26.34
#> 
#> Adjusted for:
#> * chl = 192.56
#> 
#> [[7]]
#> # Predicted values of bmi
#> 
#> hyp: 1
#> 
#> age | Predicted |       95% CI
#> ------------------------------
#>   1 |     29.55 | 27.64, 31.46
#>   2 |     25.64 | 23.98, 27.30
#>   3 |     21.73 | 18.87, 24.58
#> 
#> hyp: 2
#> 
#> age | Predicted |       95% CI
#> ------------------------------
#>   1 |     30.48 | 27.60, 33.37
#>   2 |     26.57 | 24.31, 28.84
#>   3 |     22.66 | 19.79, 25.53
#> 
#> Adjusted for:
#> * chl = 192.92
#> 
#> [[8]]
#> # Predicted values of bmi
#> 
#> hyp: 1
#> 
#> age | Predicted |       95% CI
#> ------------------------------
#>   1 |     28.04 | 26.02, 30.07
#>   2 |     25.29 | 23.62, 26.97
#>   3 |     22.55 | 19.48, 25.62
#> 
#> hyp: 2
#> 
#> age | Predicted |       95% CI
#> ------------------------------
#>   1 |     29.09 | 25.15, 33.04
#>   2 |     26.34 | 23.11, 29.58
#>   3 |     23.60 | 19.96, 27.23
#> 
#> Adjusted for:
#> * chl = 187.20
#> 
#> [[9]]
#> # Predicted values of bmi
#> 
#> hyp: 1
#> 
#> age | Predicted |       95% CI
#> ------------------------------
#>   1 |     28.35 | 26.33, 30.37
#>   2 |     25.06 | 22.85, 27.26
#>   3 |     21.76 | 17.69, 25.84
#> 
#> hyp: 2
#> 
#> age | Predicted |       95% CI
#> ------------------------------
#>   1 |     30.93 | 26.65, 35.21
#>   2 |     27.63 | 24.85, 30.41
#>   3 |     24.34 | 21.49, 27.19
#> 
#> Adjusted for:
#> * chl = 194.56
#> 
#> [[10]]
#> # Predicted values of bmi
#> 
#> hyp: 1
#> 
#> age | Predicted |       95% CI
#> ------------------------------
#>   1 |     28.54 | 26.74, 30.34
#>   2 |     25.15 | 23.50, 26.79
#>   3 |     21.75 | 18.64, 24.87
#> 
#> hyp: 2
#> 
#> age | Predicted |       95% CI
#> ------------------------------
#>   1 |     32.04 | 27.92, 36.15
#>   2 |     28.65 | 25.61, 31.68
#>   3 |     25.25 | 22.25, 28.26
#> 
#> Adjusted for:
#> * chl = 199.08

Created on 2024-04-25 with reprex v2.1.0

Thank you Carl, I will give that a shot, would you know alternate ways to parallelize ggpredict either using dopar or other methods in case future_map does not work  with lsplines?

Is lsplines used in the model fit step or is it used by ggpredict? If the former, then it should work. If the latter, then could you clarify how it's used in a single ggpredict call, i.e. how is it used in ggpredict(model_fit[[1]], c("age[all]", "hyp"))?

So far I've found that anything that works with purrr::map() works equally well with furrr::future_map(); just need the plan bit first.

good question, yes I am including age as spline variable in the model.

@BenBolker. may be you know ?

I've updated the answer with lspline in the model. Sorry, I hadn't noticed that bit had changed from the prior question. It seems to work fine in future_map().

that works on this test dataset. Thanks.
